# How to implement UWP the right way

Tags: xaml, uwp, user-controls

I run often into many problems which leads to refactoring my code...

That is why I want to ask for some recommendations.

The problems I'm running into are:

**1) Providing data to XAML**

Providing simple data to control value instead of using a value converter. For instance I have a color string like "#FF234243" which is stored in a class. The value for the string is provided by a web application so I can only specify it at runtime.

**2) UI for every resolution**

In the beginnings of my learning I got told that you can create a UI for every possible resolution, which is stupid.
So I've written a ValueConverter which I bind on an element and as ConverterParameter I give a value like '300' which gets calculated for every possible resolution... But this leads to code like this...

```
<TextBlock
Height={Binding Converter={StaticResource SizeValue}, ConverterParameter='300'}
/>
```

**3) DependencyProperties vs. NotifyProperties(Properties which implement INotifyPropertyChanged) vs. Properties**

I have written a control which takes a list of value and converts them into *Buttons* which are clickable in the UI. So I did it like this I created a variable which I set as *DataContext* for this specific *Control* and validate my data with *DataContextChanged* but my coworker mentioned that for this reason *DependencyProperties* where introduced. So I created a *DependecyProperty* which takes the list of items **BUT** when the property gets a value I have to render the buttons... So I would have to do something like

```
public List<string> Buttons
        {
            get { return (List<string>)GetValue(ButtonsProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ButtonsProperty, value);
                RenderButtons();
            }
        }
        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Buttons.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Buttons", typeof(List<string>), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(""));

        private void RenderButtons()
        {
            ButtonBar.Children.Clear();
            ButtonBar.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();

            if(Buttons != null)
            {
                int added = 0;
                foreach (var item in Buttons)
                {
                    var cd = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) };
                    var btn = new Button() { Content = item };
                    ButtonBar.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd);
                    ButtonBar.Children.Add(btn);
                    Grid.SetColumn(btn, added);
                }
            }
        }
```

And have to use it like this:

```
<Controls:MyControl
    x:Name="ButtonBar" Button="{Binding MyButtons}">
</Controls:MyControl>
```

Since these are a lot of topics I could seperate those but I think that this is a pretty common topic for beginners and I have not found a got explanation or anything else

Comment: Each topic given should be a separate question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: In 1st problem, did you mean to avoid using of value converter and directly use the hex color string with the control, isn't ?... The hex color string is a property of a model class.. ??

Comment: @AshiqHassan yes it is a hex color but the proble ist that users can set it in a web application and in this it is not ARGB but RGB so it cant be registered that easy so I would like to use a solidcolorbrush as resource of my page and the real value should be provided by a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Providing data to XAML**

There are two options: prepare data in the ViewModel or to use converter.
To my mind using converter is better since you can have crossplatform viewModel with color like you mentioned in your example and converter will create platform dependent color. We had similar problem with image. On android it should be converted to Bitmap class, while on UWP it's converted to BitmapImage class. In the viewModel we have byte[].

**2. UI for every resolution**

You don't need to use converter, since Height is specified in effective pixels which will suit all the required resolutions automatically for you. More info can be found at the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/layouts-with-xaml

There are two options how to deal with textblock sizes:

a) Use predefined textblock styles and don't invent the wheel (which is the recommended option):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/typography#type-ramp

Or

b) Specify font size in pixels. They are not pixels, but effective pixels. They will be automatically scaled on different devices:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/typography#size-and-scaling

Furthermore, use [adaptive layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/layouts-with-xaml#adaptive-layouts-with-visual-states-and-state-triggers) to have different Layout for different screen sizes.

**3) DependencyProperties vs. NotifyProperties(Properties which implement INotifyPropertyChanged) vs. Properties**

As per your code you can try to use [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/listview-and-gridview) or [ItemsControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl) and define custom item template.

DependencyProperties are created in DependencyObject and are accessible in xaml. All controls are inherited from DependencyObjects. Usually you create them when you want to set them in xaml. They are not stored directly in the objects, but in the global dictionary and resolved at runtime.

DependencyProperties were created long time ago and you can find lots of links which explain them in details:

http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html

https://techpunch.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/wpf-wf-what-is-a-dependency-property/

[When should I use dependency properties in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592630/when-should-i-use-dependency-properties-in-wpf?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[What is a dependency property? What is its use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390331/what-is-a-dependency-property-what-is-its-use?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[What is a dependency property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617312/what-is-a-dependency-property)

INotifyPropertyChanged INPC are the central part of MVVM. You bind your view to viewModel which implements INPC and when you change value of the property control is notified and rereads the new value.

Download the following video in high resolution which explains MVVM in details (by Laurent Bugnion):
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/OPN03

[MVVM: Tutorial from start to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish)

Normal properties are used in model classes or when there is no need to notify UI regarding changes.

Comment: Since these are a lot of sources I will try to look them as soon as possible. If I would accept your answer should I splitt those topics to 3 posts and link them in the description so you can get your point or should I keep it as a single post so other users will see that these are related questions?

Comment: Regarding to listview in question 3: My problem was that I gave the option to set columnindexes fpr the buttons so that their could be two buttons at the same spot but on was visible and the other one was collapsed. Their state could be changed by easily accessing the list and set their state instead of changing the complete list and force a complete update of the UI. But would it make a differnce if I would just change the source as in perfromance and maintenance

Comment: @MelloPs you can split your question in case you are not satisfied with the answer. In the future don't create list of questions since new users won't be able to find answers since your Title does not have specific keywords regarding the question.

Comment: @MelloPs as for the third question it's fine to have custom control, but dependency property should be something like list of commands, not list of buttons. If you look at ListView implementation they don't have list of controls but list of data (Items) for the control.

Comment: Now I'm trying to work through the TuTs but this answer helped me a lot already. Thank you really much.