# Databinding on user control

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, user-controls

I have a list box which contains a usercontrol. And the user controls 2-3 text boxes defined in it.How do i enable data binding on those text boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create `DependencyProperty`-s for each of them, and you can directly bind through the xaml like so:

```
<user:MyControl txtBox1="{Binding Field1}" txtBox2="{Binding Field2}" ... />
```

To create a `DependencyProperty`, you can be as lazy as writing `"propdp" + TAB`. There are tons of articles, blog posts and general information available on the subject of `DependencyProperty`s, so have at it. A good place to start would be:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx

[What is a dependency property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617312/what-is-a-dependency-property)

Good luck! They're really fun to work with. :-)