# Xaml:Binding only left margin

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, margin

I have written this code:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                <Grid Height="30" Width="70" x:Name="grid">
                    <Border>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                    <Separator>
                        <Separator.Margin>
                            <Thickness Left="{Binding Path=Width,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Label}}" Top="0" Right="0" Bottom="0"/>
                        </Separator.Margin>
                        <Separator.LayoutTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle='120'/>
                        </Separator.LayoutTransform>
                    </Separator>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

I want to bind only left margin of separator, but this code gives me error.
Any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Binding can only be applied to a `DependencyProperty`:
[What is a dependency property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617312/what-is-a-dependency-property)

`Thickness.Left` isn't a dependency property, so you'll have to bind the whole `Margin` (which *is* a dependency property). To adjust only the left edge, you could create a `ValueConverter` that takes the `Width` and returns a `Thickness`. Example:

```
<Separator Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Label},
                            Path=Width,
                            Converter={StaticResource MyLeftMarginConverter}}" >
    <Separator.LayoutTransform>
        ...
```