# ObservableCollection updating List

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, time, ticker

I am new in WPF and MVVM also. I'm searching for USB devices in my program. But if I connect a new device, it is required to restart program to became visible.

How to do it, that refresh immediately.

Currently I have in my class in which I search device this:

```
public List<Devices> devices = new List<Devices>();

    public void FindDevices() // spremeni v public bool da dobis feedback 
    {


        _deviceList = HidDevices.Enumerate(VendorID, ProductID).ToArray();

...     devices.Add(new Devices()
            {
                DeviceId = nod + 1,
                ManufacturerId = deviceManufacturerstring[nod],
                ProductId = deviceProductstring[nod],
                SerialNumberId = deviceSNstring[nod],
                HardwareVersionId = "test4",
                FirmwareVersionId = "test5",
                DateOfManufaturedId = "test6"

            });
```

On hole for loop I add device to List. I need for loop because I read some data from each device.

I later add this devices in List in ViewModel:

```
public class Windows1ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Devices> devfuck { get; protected set; }
    List<Devices> _devicelist;

    public List<Devices> Devices
    {
        get { return _devicelist; }
        set { _devicelist = value; }
    }

    public Windows1ViewModel()
    {

        USBmiddleware cs = new USBmiddleware();
        cs.FindDevices();


        devfuck = new ObservableCollection<Devices>();


        foreach (var item in cs.devices)
        {
            devfuck.Add(item);
        }

        List<Devices> keks = cs.devices;



        NotifyPropertyChanged("devfuck");
    }


    public List<Devices> lvdevices
    {
        get { return _devicelist; }
        set { _devicelist = value; }
    }
```

What to change? Where to add INotifyPropertyChanged? Or how to solve my problem?
Please for help. Thanks!

My ViewModelBase

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{


    protected ViewModelBase()
    {
    }



    #region DisplayName


    public virtual string DisplayName { get; protected set; }

    #endregion // DisplayName

    #region Debugging Aides


    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        // Verify that the property name matches a real,  
        // public, instance property on this object.
        if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
        {
            string msg = "Invalid property name: " + propertyName;

            if (this.ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName)
                throw new Exception(msg);
            else
                Debug.Fail(msg);
        }
    }


    protected virtual bool ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName { get; private set; }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChangedAll(object inOjbect)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in inOjbect.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged(pi.Name);
        }
    }
    public virtual void Refresh()
    {
        NotifyPropertyChangedAll(this);
    }



    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.OnDispose();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Child classes can override this method to perform 
    /// clean-up logic, such as removing event handlers.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void OnDispose()
    {
    }



    ~ViewModelBase()
    {
        string msg = string.Format("{0} ({1}) ({2}) Finalized", this.GetType().Name, this.DisplayName, this.GetHashCode());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg);
    }


}
```

Comment: I think your `devfuck` property needs to be a `Dependency Property` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617312/what-is-a-dependency-property

Comment: When `FindDevices()` is invoked?

Comment: Try Adding a timer which calls cs.FindDevices() ever how often you need the list to be refreshed.

Comment: Love that variable name :-)  You could implement INotifyPropertyChanged or as @Ralt says use a dependency property which has property notifications built in.  Use "propdp" to generate a code snippet in VS.

Comment: Is possible to do with eventhandler? When new device is inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using a timer which gets called ever so often (as needed). Of course it would be sexier if you could do this using event management...

Thankfully there is a way to do this :

```
var watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
var query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE       EventType = 2");
watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
watcher.Query = query;
watcher.Start();
```

as stated here: [Detecting USB drive insertion and removal using windows service and c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620144/detecting-usb-drive-insertion-and-removal-using-windows-service-and-c-sharp)

You can then subscribe to the event and invoke your

```
FindDevices()
```

From there.

Comment: And how for remove event? Where is there any difference?

Comment: Now when I like to call FindDevice(), show error: "Error 2 No overload for method FindDevices' takes 0 arguments". What I must fix?

Comment: Sounds like you have changed your FindDevice() method and have added some properties that you pass to that method...if you have something like `public void FindDevice(string blahblah)` you can't pass it without that parameter

Comment: Alternatively you can make the the parameter optional by adding a default value `public void FindDevices(string bldsa="default")`

Comment: I add "object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e", when I delete this then I have error in "new EventArrivedEventHandler(FindDevices);" ... Error is "Error 2 No overload for 'FindDevices' matches delegate 'System.Management.EventArrivedEventHandler'"

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) in your `Windows1ViewModel` class. Then you need to call it from your property setter, or after you set the property as you are currently doing.

Next, you should set up a [`DispatcherTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx) to call your `FindDevices` method every so often and then update the `ObservableCollection` property from there.

Comment: Thanks. I update my post. ViewModelBase already vontain INotifyPropertyChanged