# xaml inside xaml. How to bind controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I have xaml inside an xaml. The inside xaml has some bindings which are giving some problems. To explain here is my code

Main xaml

```
<TabItem Header="Configuration" DataContext="{Binding ComponentsVM}">
  <Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SomeComponent}" SelectedIndex="0"/>
     <ig:MyInsideXamlElement Content="{Binding MyUserControl}" DataContext="{Binding}" />
  </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

The inside xaml is

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MySearchPath}"/>
</Grid>
```

The `MyUserControl` property displays my binding of `UserControl` without problems. But the `MySearchPath` property does not get updated with entity framework class. I suspect the binding of my inner xaml(`MySearchPath`) does not get resolved because the whole tab item's datacontext is `ComponentsVM`. Is there any way to give a second datacontext to the inner xaml?

Comment: What does the object that you are binding to look like?

Comment: I am using various data entry text boxes in various controls and all these internal controls are binding controls. It was no point giving mutiple TextBox controls in my example hence limited it to one

Comment: Define a [dependency property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617312/what-is-a-dependency-property) and bind to what do you want.

Comment: How can I make dependency property to change the data context of the inner xaml?