Binding to TreeViewItem.IsExpanded works only one way
I have the following control (excerpted)
    <TreeView x:Name="provenanceTree" 
                  Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ProvenanceTreeItems}" SelectionMode="Single"
                  >
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:IProvenance">
                <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}" IsExpanded="{x:Bind isExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <!-- The template - not relevant here, I think -->
                </TreeViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>

The idea, of course, is that I want to be able to expand and compress the tree view items from the data source.  isExpanded is defined in the implementation of IProvenance thus:
        public static DependencyProperty isExpandedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof (isExpanded), 
            typeof (bool), 
            typeof (Expandable), 
            new PropertyMetadata (false));

        public bool isExpanded {
            get=> (bool)GetValue(isExpandedProperty);
            set => SetValue(isExpandedProperty, value);
        }

Nothing alarming there , I think.
My problem is that the two-way binding seems not to be working.  When new items are added to the tree, the value in isExpanded is honoured (as I can show by changing the propertyMetadata).  When I expand and compress the items using the UI, isExpanded gets updated correctly.  But when I change isExpanded in code after the tree has been populated, nothing happens.  (The value updates correctly - I've seen that in the debugger - it's just that the treeview doesn't change.)
I found this answer, but I don't think it helps me because I'm in Winui 3 (where HierarchicalDataTemplate isn't available, and binding inside styles is problematical).
What have I forgotten?

I'm not sure why you need dependency properties there. Also is unclear what IProvenance and Expandable are.

I just posted an answer with a basic example code that works. But if you need to work with dependency properties anyway, please share more code around there.

"I'm not sure why you need dependency properties there"
Because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617312/what-is-a-dependency-property, and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth (especially where it says "you need to make your binding source observable to the binding object ...One way of doing that is to derive the class that represents your binding source from DependencyObject ... A more lightweight way of making a class observable... is to implement System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged. "

Generally speaking, you use Dependency Object for controls, and INotifyPropertyChanged for ViewModels/Models.

And the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm helps you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. You can avoid tons of boilerplate code.

Let me show you a working example of the TreeView that expands when its child is expanded:
Shell.xaml
<Page
    x:Class="WinUIApp1.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUIApp1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <StackPanel
            Grid.Row="0"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button
                Click="AddingTestButton_Click"
                Content="Adding Test" />
            <Button Content="Expanding Test" Click="ExpandingTestButton_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TreeView
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
                    <TreeViewItem
                        Content="{x:Bind Content}"
                        IsExpanded="{x:Bind IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>

</Page>

Shell.xaml.cs
public sealed partial class Shell : Page
{
    public Shell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddTestItems();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; } = [];

    private Item? LastAddedItem { get; set; }

    private void AddTestItems()
    {
        var item1 = new Item("Item 1");
        var item1Child1 = new Item("Item 1-1");
        var item1GrandChild1 = new Item("Item 1-1-1");
        var item1GrandChild2 = new Item("Item 1-1-2");
        item1Child1.Children.Add(item1GrandChild1);
        item1Child1.Children.Add(item1GrandChild2);
        item1.Children.Add(item1Child1);
        Items.Add(item1);

        var item2 = new Item("Item 2");
        var item2Child1 = new Item("Item 2-1");
        var item2GrandChild1 = new Item("Item 2-1-1");
        var item2GrandChild2 = new Item("Item 2-1-2");
        item2Child1.Children.Add(item2GrandChild1);
        item2Child1.Children.Add(item2GrandChild2);
        item2.Children.Add(item2Child1);
        Items.Add(item2);
    }

    private void AddingTestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newItem = new Item("Item 1-1-3");
        Items[0].Children[0].Children.Add(newItem);
        TreeViewControl.SelectedItem = Items[1];
        LastAddedItem = newItem;
    }

    private void ExpandingTestButton_Click(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Items[0].IsExpanded = true;
        //Items[0].Children[0].IsExpanded = true;

       if (LastAddedItem is not null)
       {
           LastAddedItem.IsExpanded = true;
       }
    }
}

Item.cs
public partial class Item : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _isExpanded;

    public Item(string content)
    {
        Content = content;
        Children.CollectionChanged += Children_CollectionChanged;
    }

    public event EventHandler<bool>? IsExpandedChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Children { get; } = [];

    public string Content { get; }

    private void Children_CollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Item child in e.NewItems)
            {
                child.IsExpandedChanged += Child_IsExpandedChanged;
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Item child in e.OldItems)
            {
                child.IsExpandedChanged += Child_IsExpandedChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Child_IsExpandedChanged(object? sender, bool isExpanded)
    {
        if (isExpanded is true)
        {
            IsExpanded = true;
        }
    }

    partial void OnIsExpandedChanged(bool value)
    {
        IsExpandedChanged?.Invoke(this, value);
    }
}

REMARKS

ObservableObject and ObservableProperty come from the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm NuGet package.


Thanks for that  code sample.  I don't understand why you don't think the Dependency Object shouldn't work, but I tried making it using an Observable Object, and with a plain-old INotifyPropertyChanged, and I get the same behaviour. It's binding OneTime, and it's binding from the target to the source (which is the second half of the two-way binding), but it's not doing the one-way part.   I'm concluding this is some kind of failure in the binding, not an error in the source.

I'm not saying that DependencyObject doesn't work because it should work. I'm saying that, for ViewModels,  you should prefer INotifyPropertyChanged implemented by the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm over DependencyObject.

Can you elaborate on what is not working exactly? If you tried my sample code, you should see that works as expected.

"Can you elaborate on what is not working exactly?"  Sure: as I expaliend before: When new items are added to the tree, the value in isExpanded is honoured (I can change how isExpanded is set, and it works correctly). When I expand and compress the items using the UI, isExpanded gets updated correctly (I can see that in the debugger). But when I change isExpanded in code after the tree has been populated, nothing happens. (The value updates correctly - I've seen that in the debugger - it's just that the treeview doesn't change.)

I updated my example code. It has a button that adds an item and a button that expands the last added item. IsExpanded needs to notify both the UI and its parents so they also  updates their IsExpanded.
